# My deployed File (.msi) can not be Installed on another machine

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, setup-deployment

I deployed a small application, i got the files you see in the image. I took the first file (.msi) and sent to a remote machine to let the end user installs it. However, the user gets an error that says file is missing or so (i can't remember the error message).

1. Should i send the second file "setup" along with the first one?
2. What the difference between setup.exe and .msi when they both do the exact
   same job. The odd thing setup.exe is smaller. Can you please explain?

I didn't send the second file because the (.msi) in my local machine, where i developed the application, works fine at any location regardless the location of the "setup" file.

The WinForm application is written in C# on .NET 3.5. I used VS 2008.

Thanks.

Comment: can you post the exact error message?

Comment: "Can't remember the error message" ? Then please try again (have a pen ready) before you ask here.

Comment: I just got it, its an Windows security issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

setup is nothing more than just an application that can install any pre-requisites that are needed and then calls the MSI.  If you can post the actual error message than perhaps I can also explain why the MSI didn't work.